# How can I show featured posts in 11ty

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

How can I show featured post in my home page I am using `11ty base blog` Starter

I have used  `{%- for post in collections.featured -%} {% include 'postslist.njk' %} {%- endfor -%}` but its not working.

I have added featured tag in posts

Postslist.njk - https://sourceb.in/CbfSslVH7O

Answer (score 0):

So first off, can you confirm that featured isn't empty? If you replace the include with just:

```
a post<br/>
```

does it iterate over a few items at least? Secondly, the include you tried iterates over a variable called posts:

```
{% for post in postslist | reverse %}
```

It doesn't look like it was meant to be used as you are using it. In other words, it's meant to be included *one* time, not multiple times inside a loop.